# Согласование причастного оборота

Tags: согласование

Каждая из пяти выбранных историй, играемая (ых) меняющимися составами актеров, имеет творческую постановку. - причастный оборот правильно отнести к "каждая" или к "историй"? Или можно и так и так - по смыслу?

Второй вопрос:меняющимся составом актеров или меняющимися составами актеров?

Comment: @Morkovkin а если так: разными составами актеров из семи человек / разным составом актеров из семи человек?

Comment: @Morkovkin В гугле нашел статьи и по запросу "пьеса играется разными составами", и по запросу "пьеса играется разным составом"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд только так:

**Каждая из пяти выбранных историй, играемых меняющимся составом актеров, имеет творческую постановку**

Оборот относится к неразрывному сочетанию "(из) пяти историй", т.е. согласовывается с "пять".

Если же привязывать к "каждая", то надо после "каждой" и ставить. Но это другой смысл получится. В нашем случае надо понимать, что все пять историй играются "меняющимся составом". При этом, однако, не совсем понятно меняющимся от истории к истории или внутри одной истории, это надо бы как-то раскрыть. А если "каждая играемая меняющимся", то это предполагает, что есть еще какие-то "неиграемые" или "играемые неменяющимся", что крайне сомнительно по контексту.

Насчет меняющихся составов. А кокой тут смысл во множественном? Неужели "меняющихся составов" больше одного? Т. е. как минимум два и каждый - меняющийся? такое возможно, если предполагать, что у каждой истории свой состав, причем тоже непостоянный в рамках этой одной истории. Сомнительно.

Отсюда имеем вариант, который я привел выше.